# Tapestry 4: Asset Cache Control?

Tags: browser, caching, tapestry

I use Tapestry 4, and whenever we push a release that changes any assets (image, style sheet, JS library), we get problems because users still have the old version of the asset in their browser cache. I'd like to set up some easy way to allow caching, but force a new asset download when we update the application. Simply disallowing caching entirely for assets is not an acceptable solution.

I couldn't see any existing mechanism for doing this, but I was figuring that there might be some way to tell Tapestry to add the build number to the URL, something like this:

http://www.test.com/path/to/the/asset/asset.jpg?12345

That way, every new build would make it look like a different asset to the end user.

Does Tapestry provide an easy way to solve the cache problem that I'm not aware of? If not, how would one go about modifying the URL generated by Tapestry? And how would the code responsible for doing that get the build number? (I could get the build number into a Spring bean, for example, but how would the new URL building mechanism get at it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After stewing about this problem for a long time, I eventually solved it myself. This solution assumes you have the [tapestry-spring library](http://howardlewisship.com/tapestry-javaforge/tapestry-spring/) in your project.

In my case, I have a Spring bean that contains some of my application's global properties:

```
package myapp;

public class AppProperties {
    private String build;

    public String getBuild() {
        return build;
    }

    public void setBuild(String build) {
        this.build = build;
    }

    // other properties
}
```

Declare this bean in your Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="appProperties" class="myapp.AppProperties">
    <property name="build" value="@BUILD_NUMBER@"/>
</bean>
```

You can set up your Ant build script to replace `@BUILD_NUMBER@` with the actual number (see the [Copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task in the Ant manual for details).

Now create a class that will wrap `IAsset`s and tack the build number onto the URL:

```
package myapp;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.hivemind.Location;
import org.apache.hivemind.Resource;
import org.apache.tapestry.IAsset;

public class BuildAwareAssetWrapper implements IAsset {
    private IAsset wrapped;
    private String build;

    public BuildAwareAssetWrapper(IAsset wrapped, String build) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.build = build;
    }

    public String buildURL() {
        return addParam(wrapped.buildURL(), "build", build);
    }

    public InputStream getResourceAsStream() {
        return wrapped.getResourceAsStream();
    }

    public Resource getResourceLocation() {
        return wrapped.getResourceLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return wrapped.getLocation();
    }

    private static String addParam(String url, String name, String value) {
        if (url == null) url = "";
        char sep = url.contains("?") ? '&' : '?';
        return url + sep + name + '=' + value;
    }
}
```

Next, we need to make Tapestry wrap all assets with our wrapper. The `AssetSourceImpl` class is responsible for providing `IAsset` instances to Tapestry. We'll extend this class and override the `findAsset()` method so that we can wrap the created assets with the wrapper class:

```
package myapp;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.hivemind.Location;
import org.apache.hivemind.Resource;
import org.apache.tapestry.IAsset;
import org.apache.tapestry.asset.AssetSourceImpl;

public class BuildAwareAssetSourceImpl extends AssetSourceImpl {
    private AppProperties props;

    @Override
    public IAsset findAsset(Resource base, String path, Locale locale, Location location) {
        IAsset asset = super.findAsset(base, path, locale, location);
        return new BuildAwareAssetWrapper(asset, props.getBuild());
    }

    public void setAppProperties(AppProperties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
}
```

Notice that the implementation has a setter which can accept our Spring bean. The last step is to get Tapestry to use `BuildAwareAssetSourceImpl` to create assets instead of `AssetSourceImpl`. We do this by overriding the corresponding service point in `hivemodule.xml`:

```
<!-- Custom asset source -->
<implementation service-id="tapestry.asset.AssetSource">
    <invoke-factory service-id="hivemind.BuilderFactory" model="singleton">
        <construct class="myapp.BuildAwareAssetSourceImpl">
            <set-object property="appProperties" value="spring:appProperties"/>
            <set-configuration property="contributions" configuration-id="tapestry.asset.AssetFactories"/>
            <set-service property="lookupAssetFactory" service-id="tapestry.asset.LookupAssetFactory"/>
            <set-service property="defaultAssetFactory" service-id="tapestry.asset.DefaultAssetFactory"/>
        </construct>
    </invoke-factory>
</implementation>
```

That's it. If you run your application and view the source for any page that uses an asset, you will see that the URL will have the new `build` parameter on it.

Comment: Correct. Although I recently discovered that it can cause some problems with Dojo stuff, so I had to change the code to exclude those from getting the build number tacked on. Still works for my own assets, though, which are far more likely to change.

Comment: By the way, if you find this useful (or cool), I wouldn't mind upvotes on the question and answer. :)