# How can I override the URL writing mechanism for .script <include-script> tags in Tapestry 4?

Tags: caching, browser, tapestry

Previously on StackOverflow, I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288041/tapestry-4-asset-cache-control) where I asked how to append a build number parameter to the generated URLs for Tapestry assets to solve caching problems. I ultimately answered my own question: replace Tapestry's default asset source with a custom one which wraps the generated assets to tack on the build number. But I've found out that .js files imported by the `<include-script>` tag in .script files are not using this mechanism and are therefore not getting the build number on them. So I'd like to accomplish the same objective with them. How?

Comment: you probably know this, but this behaviour is standard in T5